# Using React component to handle all text on my website

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, text, components

In my React app, in an effort to handle all (most) of the text needed for different parts of my sports analytics website, I built a component `<PageText>`. Text is needed throughout this website to explain the details of graphs and statistical tables, and in general text is needed throughout, and I wanted to centralize all of this text in one place. I figured creating a component would be a better approach than having dozens (hundreds soon) of `<p>` tags with different texts / styles / etc. spread across 25 - 50 different container components of mine.

When I call `<PageText>`, it looks like this:

```
<PageText usedFor='section' pageName='TeamLanding' textNum={2} />
<PageText usedFor='section' playerName={playerFullName} teamName={teamNameMarket} pageName='PlayerLineups' />
<PageText usedFor='table' tableName='TeamSeason' textNum={1} />
...etc
```

They take the mandatory props `usedFor` and `textNum`, as well as a dozen or so (and growing) optional props used in specific text sentences.

And here is the entirety of the `PageText` component (don't need read the whole thing, just skim for structure):

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import React from 'react';

function PageText({ usedFor, pageName, tableName, teamName, playerName, confName, chartName, scope, textNum, shotData, lineupScope, numQualTeams, sizeAdj = 1 }) {

    PageText.defaultProps = {
        sizeAdj: 1,
        textNum: 1,
        confName: 'MEGA'
    };

    let brandBlue = '#0066CC';

    // Styles
    let sectionStyle = { fontSize: `calc(${sizeAdj} * 1em)`, fontStyle: 'italic', lineHeight: '1.25' };
    let tableStyle = { fontSize: `calc(${sizeAdj} * 0.85em)`, fontStyle: 'italic', lineHeight: '1.25', paddingTop: '3px', margin: 0 };
    let moreInfoStyles = { padding: '8px' };

    // each userFor + pageName pairing has 3 different texts to show. 
    let text1, text2, text3;

    // usedFor: ['section', 'table', 'moreInfo';
    // usedFor helps with segmenting the texts into groups, and are used to style the <p> tags differently based on use of text. 
    //pageName: all of the different names of pages on my website (the parent components where text will be displayed)

    if (usedFor === 'section') {
        switch (pageName) {
            case 'TeamLanding':
                text1 = <p style={sectionStyle}>The tables below display team-season statistics.</p>;
                text2 = <p style={sectionStyle}><span style={{ color: brandBlue, fontWeight: '700' }}>Trial Access:</span> Team-season statistics available for trial teams only - sign up for a full subscription to access statistics for all available NCAA teams.</p>;
                text3 = <p style={sectionStyle}><span style={{ color: brandBlue, fontWeight: '700' }}>Tips:</span> Tables are interactive. Table headers are hoverable (help tooltip) and clickable (sort columns). Logos and names within tables are hyperlinks useful for website navigation.</p>;
                break;
            case 'TeamScatter':
                text1 = <p style={sectionStyle}>Welcome to the <span style={{ fontWeight: '700', color: '#0066CC' }}>Team-Verse Logo Plotting Application</span> - designed to visually compare teams across your choice of team stats. Use the select widgets below to toggle between seasons, to filter by conference, and to select the stats for each axis. Tips - use the "Suggested Graphs" widget to automatically select between statistical pairings for the axes that intuitively go well together, or click the "Random Axes" button to randomly select statistics for the axes. Also, toggle the "Exc/Inc Opp Stats" button to add opponent stats (stats each team allowed to opponents) to the X-Axis and Y-Axis select widgets.</p>;

                break;
            case 'TeamPlayerStats':
                text1 = <p style={sectionStyle}>The tables below display player-season statistics for {teamName}. The large yellow/orange/red numbers show each player's <span style={{ color: brandBlue, fontWeight: 700 }}> 0 - 100 percentile rating </span>in that statistic, with 100 being the best and 0 the worst. The minutes filter below can be used to change the minumum-minutes requirement to appear in the tables below. Column headers are hoverable and include a short explanation of the stat.</p>;
                text2 = <p style={sectionStyle}>The Assister-Scorer Network is a graph consisting of nodes (for each player) and links (for each pair of players) that represents the frequency with which players on {teamName} assist each other’s baskets - the graph helps to answer the question “Who is assisting who on this team?”</p>;
                text3 = <p style={sectionStyle}><span style={{ color: brandBlue, fontWeight: '700' }}>Tips:</span> Hover a node to reveal its tooltip, or click on a node to reverse the direction of the arrows / links. Use the select to choose the number of players to display in the network graph, but beware of including too many players, which will clutter the graph. Click the Show ROP (rest of players) button to display additional nodes for bench players on the team not included in the base graph.</p>;
                break;
            case 'TeamGameRecaps':
                text1 = <p style={sectionStyle}>The tables below display team-game boxscore statistics for {teamName}. Use the select widget below to choose between the 6 different table options. Use the table headers to sort the columns, revealing the team's best and worst games for each statistic, and helping to uncover which statistics are most correlated with winning and losing games.</p>;
                text2 = <p style={sectionStyle}>The graph below displays, for the selected statistic, {teamName}'s performance in that statistic for each game, along with their 5-game rolling average for that statistic. Note that toggling the table select widget above will update the graph select widget below with different stat options for the graph.</p>;
                break;                
            case 'PlayerLanding':
                text1 = <p style={sectionStyle}>The table below displays player-season statistics and percentile ratings across all division-I players. Use the select widgets to choose amongst the 5 different tables (Offensive, Defensive, Shooting Overall, Shooting By Distance, Shooting by Court Zone), and to filter these tables for players from specific conferences. Note that statistics in the <strong>Shooting By Distance</strong> and <strong>Shooting By Court Zone</strong> tables are computed using play-by-play data that is not available for all division-I basketball games.</p>;
                text2 = <p style={sectionStyle}><span style={{ color: brandBlue, fontWeight: '700' }}>Trial Access:</span> Player-season statistics available for players on trial teams only - sign up for a full subscription to access statistics for all available NCAA players. Conference filter disabled on trial accounts.</p>;
                text3 = <p style={sectionStyle}><span style={{ color: brandBlue, fontWeight: '700' }}>Tips:</span> Tables are interactive. Table headers are hoverable (short stat explanations) and clickable (sortable columns), and logos and player names within the table are hyperlinks useful for navigation of the platform.</p>;
                break;
            case 'PlayerScatter':
                text1 = <p style={sectionStyle}>Use the player-verse scatter plotting application to compare players across chosen statistics. Use the select widgets below to toggle the various graph filters, and to change the stats on each axis. See below for additional information.</p>;
                break;
            case 'PlayerComps':
                text1 = <p style={sectionStyle}>CBB Comps is a model for computing similarity scores across players using selected metrics, where scores are computed based solely on the differences between the player's percentile rankings in the selected metrics. Choose your own metrics below, and see which players are most similar to {playerName} across those metrics. Similarity scores range from a minimum of -100 (zero similarity) to +100 (perfect similarity).</p>;
                break;
            case 'GameRecaps':
                text1 = <p style={sectionStyle}>Each team's statistical performance is summarized below, with key game statistics grouped into 6 categories: (1) Ball Control, (2) Shooting, (3) Play Style, (4) Four Factors, (5) Scoring by Play Context, and (6) Defense. Black numbers reflect the raw stat values, and the large yellow/orange/red numbers reflect each team's <span style={{ color: brandBlue, fontWeight: 700 }}> 0 - 100 percentile rating </span>for all games played by all teams in that statistic for the season, with 100 being the best game and 0 being the worst game.</p>;
                text2 = <p style={sectionStyle}>Marker Charts and Heatmaps for each team's shooting performance in this game - use the button above to the right to toggle between graph types, and to toggle the level of detail in the graphs. Note that heatmaps suffer from a small-sample-size challenge for single games.</p>;
                text3 = <p style={sectionStyle}>Break down each team's shooting performance at the most detailed level. Shooting by zone / by distance graphs highlight the effectiveness and frequency of team shooting by region of the court. Use the buttons above to the right to toggle between zone and distance graphs, and to toggle the level of detail in the graphs.</p>;
                break;
            default: text1 = ``; text2 = ``; text3 = ``;
        }
    }

    if (usedFor === 'table') {
        switch (tableName) {
            case 'TeamSeason':
                text1 = <p style={tableStyle}>Black numbers reflect stat values, and large colored numbers reflect each team's <strong>{scope === 'conf' ? 'Conference' : 'Division-I'} ranking</strong>> in each stat, against {scope === 'conf' ? `opposing teams in the ${confName}` : `all Division-I teams`}.</p>;
                text2 = <p style={tableStyle}>Due to limited availability of play-by-play data with shooting coordinates for smaller-conference schools, <strong>only {numQualTeams} teams</strong> qualify for detailed shooting rankings.</p>;
                text3 = <p style={tableStyle}>Large colored numbers reflect each team's <strong>conference ranking</strong> in each stat, against opposing teams in the {confName}.</p>;
                break;
            case 'PlayerSeason': text1 = <p style={tableStyle}>Black numbers reflect stat values, and large colored numbers reflect each player's <strong>0 - 100 percentile rating</strong> for each stat, across qualifying players in the top 6 conferences.</p>; break;
            case 'TeamGame': text1 = <p style={tableStyle}>Black numbers reflect stat values, and large yellow/orange/red numbers reflect the team's <strong>0 - 100 percentile rating</strong> in each game, compared to games played by all teams in that stat for the season.</p>; break;
            default: text1 = ``; text2 = ``; text3 = ``;
        }
    }

    if (usedFor === 'moreInfo') {
        switch (pageName) {
            case 'PlayerScatter':
                text1 =
                    (<div style={moreInfoStyles}>
                        <p>The Player-Verse is a scatter plotting application for comparing players across selected statistics. tables below display team-season statistics for teams that play in the top 6 division-I basketball conferences (ACC, Big East, Big 12, Big 10, SEC, Pac12), along with the OVC (Ohio Valley Conference) temporarily. Note that column headers are hoverable (include a short explanation of the stat) and clickable (to sort the columns). Tip - click on the conference logos, team logos, and team names within the tables to navigate to various pages on the website.</p>
                        <p>The tables below display team-season statistics for teams that play in the top 6 division-I basketball conferences (Ation of the stat) and clickable (to sort the columns). Tip - click on the conference logos, team logos, and team names within the tables to navigate to various pages on the website.</p>
                        <p>The tables below display team-season statistics for teams that play in the top 6 division-I basketball conferences (ACC, Big East, Big 12, Big 10, SEC, Pac12), along with the OVC (Ohio Valley Conpages on the website.</p>
                    </div>);
                break;
            case 'ShotCharts':
                text1 =
                    (<div style={moreInfoStyles}>
                        <div>
                            <div className='checkbox-btn' style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}>
                                <input
                                    style={{ margin: '0' }}
                                    type='checkbox'
                                    className='checkbox'
                                />
                                <div className='toggler' data-label-checked='Yes' data-label-unchecked='No' />
                            </div>
                            <p style={{ marginLeft: '10px', display: 'inline' }}><strong>Appwide vs. Chartwide: </strong> Use the "Yes/No" toggle switches to switch the scope of the select widgets and other buttons between Appwide and Chartwide. Appwide widgets (the main row of selects atop the page) control all 4 shot charts at once, whereas chartwide widgets (appear upon toggling) control their specific shot chart.</p>
                        </div>
                        <p style={{ marginTop: '1rem' }}><strong>Att Freq & FG Pct:</strong> Our "region" chart types (Zone and Dist) include the option to display either (a) net field goal percentages (FG%), or (b) net field goal attempt frequency (FGA Freq), as the metric used for coloring the graph. FG% shot charts provide insights into how effective a team shoots from a particular location, whereas FGA Freq shot charts provide insight into how frequently a team shoots from a particular location, all relative to league average.</p>
                        <p><strong>Offense & Defense:</strong> In addition to the standard offensive shot charts, the shot visualizer is also able to generate defensive shot charts at the team level via the "Offense/Defense" button, providing unique insights into the defensive shot profile that each team allows.</p>
                        <p><strong>Navigate Faster:</strong> This helper select allows you to quickly load several shot charts that pair well together with a single click. For example, selecting "Team's Top 4 Players" will identify the 4 players on the first team (the team whose shot chart is in the top-left) with the most shot attempts, and load all 4 of their shot charts. Note that each of the options in this helper select load charts for the first team, so select the team you'd like in the first chart before using the helper select.</p>
                    </div>);
                break;
            default:
                text1 = ``;
        }
    }

    let returnText;
    switch (textNum) {
        case 1: returnText = text1; break;
        case 2: returnText = text2; break;
        case 3: returnText = text3; break;
        default: returnText = text1;
    }

    return (
        returnText
    );
}

export default PageText;
```

In short, I thought this was a smart approach initially, as I was repeating the task of putting `<p>` tags across all of my container components. However currently the component feels as if it's not built well, and it seems highly limiting, in particular:

- it doesn't do a good job of handling different styles. The prop `sizeAdj` is meant to be a prop that increases the text size, but having props like this for all styles makes little sense. Also different p-tags need different margins / paddings on my website, and if the default margin/padding for this component doesn't match what is needed, I have to wrap `<PageText>` in a `<div>` tag that is solely used for margin/padding.
- I'm not really reusing these p-tags. Each sentence in the component is generally only used once or twice throughout the app.
- the component doesn't handle headers. As a result, I also have many ad hoc p-tags and h-tags spread across the website for various headers as such:

```
    <h3 className='small-graph-header'>{graph1XStat.fullName}</h3>
    <h3 className='shot-chart-sub-header'>Defensive Heatmap Allowed</h3>
    <h3 style={{ margin: '0 0 10px 0', textDecoration: 'underline', textDecorationColor: '#0066CC' }}>Defensive Shooting Allowed</h3>
```

These `<h>` tags themselves also seem messy in my website, as I sometimes use a className for them and sometimes do inline styling.

Part of me thinks I could simplify this by simply doing in-line styling for all h and p tags that don't require hover or other effects (scrap this component), but I do also like the idea of a component to organize all of this. Is there a better way to do this? I'm curious what the preferred approach to organizing all of the text on a website built with React generally is? I understand there are different ways to do the same thing in React, but knowing a general best practice here would be helpful.

**Edit:** by typing out and re-reading the post, it has become more obvious to me that I like the idea of centralizing text in a single component, but I am not properly styling different p-tags. I also don't like the growing number of props, nor do I like the convoluted way of accessing each sentence (the usedFor, textNum, pageName, etc. props).

Answer (score 1):

In my admittedly limited experience, React is intended for a) modularly building the DOM structure (your user interface) and b) managing state.

From what I can tell, you are trying to use Reactjs to manage the appearances of things, which belongs belongs in the realm of CSS, or style, broadly-speaking. While I don't have suggestions specific to your code, the better way to handle this is use one of to the many toolkits for making CSS more modular, such as Styled, emotion, or modular-CSS.

There are a lot of choices out there; to make deciding easier, read their introductory docs, and see if it's possible to add them them to your project incrementally. You can always create a branch and if it works for you (and if applicable, your team).

More if you're curious to what's out there: [Best of JS: CSS in JS tools](https://bestofjs.org/tags/css-in-js)